# Is $(2,x,y)$ maximal ideal in $\mathbb Z[x,y]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, soft-question, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I’m new to ring theory and have difficulty in showing whether an ideal $I$ is a maximal ideal of commutative ring $R$ with unity mostly when $I$ is generated by more than one element.

For example: The ideal $(x)$ is prime in the ring $\mathbb Z[x]$.

Proof: The map $\phi: \mathbb Z[x]\to \mathbb Z $ given by $\phi (f(x))=f(0)$ is an onto ring homomorphism and has kernel $(x)$. So by first isomorphism theorem, $\mathbb Z[x]/(x)\simeq \mathbb Z$. It follows that $(x)$ is prime ideal of $\mathbb Z[x]$ ($\mathbb Z$ is an integral domain and not a field).

I get stuck in the following:

> Is $(2,x,y)$ a maximal ideal of $\mathbb Z[x,y]$?

I don’t know.

I plan to use the theorem that $I$ is a maximal ideal in $R$ iff $R/I$ is a field.

By third isomorphism theorem, $\frac{\mathbb Z[x,y]/(2)}{\color{red}{(2,x,y)/(2)}}\simeq \mathbb Z[x,y]/(2,x,y).\tag 1$

I observe that the numerator in LHS is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_2[x,y]$. But I have no idea how to simplify the red part in $(1)$. So how should I simplify the red part?

I would also request to let me know some source where this type of problems (where I is generated by more than 1 element or is even more complicated than that) are explained. Thanks.

Comment: You should proceed similar as in the example. What is the kernel of $\mathbb Z[x,y]\to\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z,\ f\mapsto f(0,0)\bmod 2$?

Comment: @StefanAlbrecht: That sure solves the problem. Thanks. To find kernel, I need those $f$ in $Z[x,y]$ which have even value at the point $(0,0)$. This is the case with the constant $2$, and the polynomials $x$ and $y$. So $(2,x,y)$ is in kernel of the homomorphism. The converse can also be shown to be true using Remainder theorem. But how do I do it using the third isomorphism theorem?

Comment: In general, if $J \subseteq \langle a_1, \ldots, a_n \rangle$ then $\langle a_1, \ldots, a_n \rangle / J = \langle a_1 + J, \ldots, a_n + J \rangle = \langle \overline{a_1}, \ldots, \overline{a_n} \rangle$.  So in your case, $\langle 2,x,y \rangle / \langle 2 \rangle = \langle \overline{2}, \overline{x}, \overline{y} \rangle$ but $\overline{2} = \overline{0}$ so that term can be ignored.  So, then you need to see what the isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/\langle 2 \rangle \simeq \mathbb{Z}_2[x,y]$ does to $\overline{x}$ and $\overline{y}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\Bbb Z[x,y]/(2,x,y)\cong \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ (explanation in a comment below) is a field, so the ideal is maximal. Atiyah and Macdonald is still the standard book on commutative algebra.

Since two people asked me to include my comment in the answer and since both of them can delete comments (and answers), I include it here. The comment was posted a few minutes after the answer.

**Comment.**
Consider the homomorphism from $\Bbb Z[x,y]$ to $\Bbb Z/(2)$ which takes $x,y$ to $0$, $1$ to $1$. Such a homomorphism exists because $\Bbb Z[x,y]$ is a free commutative unital ring. The kernel $K$ of that homomorphism contains $2,x,y$, so it contains $(2,x,y)$. A polynomial not in $(2,x,y)$ must have odd free term, so it maps to $1$ (not to $0$). Hence $K=(2,x,y)$ and by the isomorphism theorem $\Bbb Z[x,y]/(2,x,y)≅\Bbb Z/(2)$.

Comment: Thanks for the response :).  I'm afraid, I still don't understand how you got the first equivalence. I think that you used the third isomorphism there (by mod out by the ideal $(2)$) but I request you to please 1) elaborate the simplification of $(2,x,y)/(x,y)$, 2) also let me know some source where I can learn/practice more of these types (where $I$ in $R/I$ is generated by more than $1$ element) of problems/exercises.

Comment: Consider the  homomorphism from $\Bbb Z[x,y]$ to $\Bbb Z/(2)$ which takes $x,y$ to $0$, $1$ to $1$. Such a homomorphism exists because $\Bbb Z[x,y]$ is a free commutative unital ring. The kernel $K$ of that homomorphism contains $2,x,y$, so it contains $(2,x,y)$.  A polynomial not in $(2,x,y)$ must have odd free term, so maps to $1$ (not to $0$). Hence $K=(2,x,y)$ and by the isomorphism theorem $\Bbb Z[x,y]/(2,x,y)\cong \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$. As for the book, any commutative algebra book will work (Atiyah and Macdonald, for example).

Comment: @Koro The path around the "other side" of the diamond might make more sense to you? $\mathbb Z[x,y]/(2,x,y)\cong (\mathbb Z[x,y]/(x,y))/((2,x,y)/(x,y))\cong \mathbb Z/(2)$. Although maybe you will feel the difficulty is the same.

Comment: I have simplified the answer a little.

Comment: @markvs Quotient is a field so the ideal is maximal is more correct isn't it?

Comment: @love_sodam: It is what is written in the answer.

Comment: "Claim (explanation in a comment below)" is not good practice for a solution, since comments are not intended to be permanent. Please make it self-contained for future readers.

Comment: @rschwieb: I think I understand now. To answer my own question about the red colored part in OP: $(2,x,y)/(2)\simeq (x,y) \mod 2$. So the quotient is $\simeq$ to $\frac{Z_2[x,y]}{(x,y) \mod 2}$. Now I map $f(x,y)\in Z_2[x,y]$ to $f(0,0)\mod 2$ in $Z_2$ and note that the kernel of this homomorphism is $(x,y)\mod 2$. The desired result follows by the first isomorphism theorem now. Thanks :).

Comment: Professor markvs, thanks a lot for answering my question on suggestion of a source to study more on these topics +1 :).

Comment: @markvs *Are you expecting that comments will be deleted?* Well, nearly, yes. Comments are not to be expected to stick around, that is true. You should [read the faq on comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) because it clearly says *only use it for temporary stuff* and *don't use it for answering* which is suggestive.  Regards

Comment: @rschwieb: It is not a part of the answer. I expected the OP to find the little argument on his/her own. My comment appeared after a question by the OP about my answer when it became clear that an explanation is needed.

Comment: @markvs that’s all well and good, and a fine application of the spoiler text feature in a solution.  As a comment it runs the risk of becoming a dangling reference at a later date is all. That’s why the advice is as it is.  I’m just trying to help your answer be its best. Regards.

Comment: As it stands right now, this answer is not a complete answer, and would more appropriately be left below the question as a comment.  Generally, I would simply move such an answer to the comments, but it appears that there is discussion below the answer which could form the basis for a more complete answer (the comments themselves, as @rschwieb points out, should be regarded as temporary and ephemeral).  Please edit your answer to incorporate some of those comments.  Otherwise, it is likely that this answer will be deleted.

Comment: I have added my comment to my answer. I am not sure if that is what the moderator wanted. He did not answer my question. Meanwhile the OP got another answer posted 2 hours after mine.

Answer (score 2):

The idea is that the quotient ring $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(2,x,y)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

How can you do it? First find a candidate homomorphism $\varphi\colon \mathbb{Z}[x,y]\to\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and the choice is almost obvious: send the integers to their residue class modulo $2$, $x\mapsto0$ and $y\mapsto0$. In other words
$$
\varphi(f(x,y))=[f(0,0)]_2
$$
The kernel certainly contains $2$, $x$ and $y$. Suppose $f(x,y)\in\ker\varphi$ and write it as
$$
f(x,y)=g_0(x)+g_1(x)y+\dots+g_n(x)y^n
$$
Then $\varphi(f(x,y))=\varphi(g_0(x))=[g_0(0]_2$ and therefore the constant term of $g_0(x)$ is even and $g_0(x)=g_0(0)+xh(x)$ for some $h(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$. Thus
$$
f(x,y)=g_0(0)+xh(x)+g_1(x)y+\dots+g_n(x)y^n\in(2,x,y)
$$
Hence $\ker\varphi=(2,x,y)$ and we're done.

Answer (score 0):

It is clear that $\rm (2,x,y)=(2)+(x,y)$. Let $\phi:Z[x,y]\to Z_2[x,y]$ be a natural homomorphism. It is clear that $\ker \phi=(2).$

By the third isomorphism theorem:

$$\frac{Z[x,y]}{(x,y,2)}\cong\frac{Z[x,y]/(\ker\phi)}{((x,y)+\ker\phi)/(\ker \phi)}\cong \frac{Z_2[x,y]}{(x,y)}\cong Z_2.$$

It follows that $(x,y,2)$ is maximal.